# PhP multidimensional array to individual array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array which I want to convert to individual arrays.

Original array is

```
$hos_pabsl = array(
    0 =>
    array(
        'tile_id' => '1',
        'tile_type' => '4',
        'title' => 'Introduction',
        'topicNum' => '1',
        'topicTitle' => 'Introduction',
        'subNum' => NULL,
    ),
    1 =>
    array(
        'tile_id' => '2',
        'tile_type' => '9',
        'title' => 'Beer',
        'topicNum' => '2',
        'topicTitle' => 'Beer',
        'subNum' => NULL,
    ),
    2 =>
    array(
        'tile_id' => '3',
        'tile_type' => '4',
        'title' => 'Methods of Brewing',
        'topicNum' => '2',
        'topicTitle' => 'Beer',
        'subNum' => NULL,
    ),
    3 =>
    array(
        'tile_id' => '4',
        'tile_type' => '11',
        'title' => 'Beer Styles',
        'topicNum' => '2',
        'topicTitle' => 'Beer',
        'subNum' => '',
    ),
);
```

I want to convert this array into individual arrays named `'tile_id' , 'tile_type' , ...`.

Currently I am doing it the following way !

```
$tile_id = [];
$tile_type = [];
$title = [];
$topicNum = [];
$topicTitle= [];
$subNum = [];

foreach($hos_pabsl as $val){
    array_push($tile_id, $val['tile_id']);
    array_push($tile_type, $val['tile_type']);
    array_push($title, $val['title']);
    array_push($topicNum, $val['topicNum']);
    array_push($topicTitle, $val['topicTitle']);
    array_push($subNum, $val['subNum']);
}
```

**Problem 1:** IS this the most efficient way (in terms of speed) to do this operation?

**Problem 2:** 
The `$hos_pabsl` array's index (or keys) are always going to be sequential. However, my problem is that for second array (at level 2 OR $hos_pabsl[0]) the index (or keys) might increase or decrease. 
E.g. all arrays in might have only 2 items 'tile_id'  & 'title'. OR might have one extra item 'description'. So how can I make the above operation dynamic ? 
To Solve problem 2, I have thought of using array_keys to extract names first   `$names = array_keys($hos_pabsl[0])` then using those names as array names like  `${$names[0]} =[]`. Again I don't think this is the right/efficient way to do this.

Any guidance on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Problem1: Micro-optimalization has little to no effect here. Go with the flow.

Comment: What do you want the result to look like and why?

Comment: I want to result to have individual arrays. E.g. `$tile_id=Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4);` and `$title = Array
(
    [0] => Introduction
    [1] => Beer
    [2] => Methods of Brewing
    [3] => Beer Styles);` and `$topicTitle = [0] => Introduction
    [1] => Beer
    [2] => Beer
    [3] => Beer);` and so on and so forth.. I am getting the original array from DB and I need individual array for separate unrelated processing in different functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running PHP 5.5, then you can use [array_column()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
$tile_id = array_column($hos_pabsl, 'tile_id');
$tile_type = array_column($hos_pabsl, 'tile_type');
... etc
```

for versions of PHP earlier than 5.5, you can use [array_map()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$tile_id = array_map(
    function ($value) { return $value['tile_id']; }, $hos_pabsl
);
$tile_type = array_map(
    function ($value) { return $value['tile_type']; }, $hos_pabsl
);
... etc
```

Comment: Don't know if this changed in PHP 5.5 but: Anonymous functions are created using `create_function(String args, String body)`, not by simply embedding them.

Comment: [Anonymous functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (closures) can be embedded as I've shown in my example since PHP version 5.3: you don't have to use create_function

Comment: Hi MarkBaker and @AbraCadaver  I have php version 5.4.4. So I tried to mix both of your methods. `foreach(array_keys(reset($hos_phsg)) as $key) {
    $$key = array_map( function ($value) { return $value[$key]; }, $hos_phsg );
}` The error I am getting is that `$key is undefined in $value[$key]. ` How can I pass this `$key` value for it to be dynamic ?

Comment: `foreach(array_keys(reset($hos_phsg)) as $key) {     $$key = array_map( function ($value) use ($key) { return $value[$key]; }, $hos_phsg ); }`

Answer (score 1):

To go with Mark Baker's answer since I was already typing it:

```
foreach(array_keys(reset($hos_pabsl)) as $key) {
    $$key = array_column($hos_pabsl, $key);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I can accept only one answer. Your answer also helped. I am trying to use combination your answer and  @MarkBaker 's answer. I tried to mix both of your methods. `foreach(array_keys(reset($hos_phsg)) as $key) {     $$key = array_map( function ($value) { return $value[$key]; }, $hos_phsg ); } ` The error I am getting is that `$key is undefined in $value[$key].`  How can I pass this $key value for it to be dynamic ?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I had tried that assuming `$key` would be available in closure function because of variable scope.  But it throws `Missing argument 2 for {closure}() in` error.

Comment: `function ($value) use ($key) { return $value[$key]; },`

Answer (score -1):

In terms of performance if the array is huge using a for instead of a foreach it will be [faster](http://www.phpbench.com/).

```
$tile_id = array();
$tile_type = array();
$title = array();
$topicNum = array();
$topicTitle = array();
$subNum = array();

$hos_pabsl_sz = count($hos_pabsl);
for ($i = 0; $i < $hos_pabsl_sz; ++$i ) {
    $tile_id[$i] = $hos_pabsl[$i]['tile_id'];
    $tile_type[$i] = $hos_pabsl[$i]['tile_type'];
    $title[$i] = $hos_pabsl[$i]['title'];
    $topicNum[$i] = $hos_pabsl[$i]['topicNum'];
    $topicTitle[$i] = $hos_pabsl[$i]['topicTitle'];
    $subNum[$i] = $hos_pabsl[$i]['subNum'];
}
```

Comment: @user2834439 Yes, but you said you wanted something faster. foreach is slower than for http://www.phpbench.com/. In most cases it doesn't matter but it still slower.

Comment: Note that the phpbench.com benchmark is using `foreach($array as $key => $val)` rather than simply `foreach($array as $val)`... including the key can make a significant performance overhead when using `foreach`; but normally `foreach` will be faster to iterate an array than `for`

Comment: @MarkBaker I agree but it is allready about 3500% slower, I don't thing that including the key or not will have a huge difference. Anyway, the only way to be sure it to benchmark it by yourself.

Comment: Check the `Read Loop: foreach() vs. for() vs. while(list() = each())` figures, I think you've just found the first reference on the phpbench.com site (`Modify Loop: foreach() vs. for() vs. while(list() = each())`), not the appropriate one for this case